# Example of an assertion which is not true for any positive integer, yet for which the induction step holds.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> Give an example of an assertion which is not true for any positive
>   integer, yet for which the induction step holds.

First of all, definition.

> In **inductive step**, we suppose that $P(k)$ is true for some positive
>   integer $k$ and then we prove that $P(k + 1)$ is true.

**My thoughts** : Since the assertion has to satisfy the induction step, it must be false for $n=1$.

But I cannot think of any such assertion.
Does anyone have any hints? Thank you.

**Edit**: Just realised that my thoughts don't make much sense, as the question demands the assertion to be false for every positive integer.

Comment: $(n > 1)$.......

Comment: Let $P(n) := (n > 1)$. Clearly $(n > 1) \to ((n+1) > 1)$ holds (because $\text F \to \text F$ is $\text T$) and thus we have that $\forall n (P(n) \to P(n+1))$ is true. But $P(1)$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortage of good answers to this question, so I'll give a couple examples in the hopes that thinking about them will help you to produce your own answers.

Two possibilities for $P(n)$ are

-the assertion that $n! = 0$

-the assertion that $n > 2n$

Comment: How does $k>2k$ imply $k+1>2(k+1)$?

Comment: From the base case also $1 > 2$

Comment: This is just saying that if $1$ is negative, every 'positive' integer is also negative

Comment: Strong induction.  $k > 2k$ and $1 > 2$ so $k+1 > 2k + 2 = 2(k+1)$.  Also by strong induction.  $n=0$.  So $n+1 = n + 0 = n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(k):k$ is irrational

$P(k): \{k\}>0$, where $\{k\}$ denotes the fractional part of $k$

Answer (score 1):

$n < n$ does not hold for any $n$ but the inductive step holds:

If $k <k$ then $k+1<k+1$

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think:

$n \le n-2$

Then $n+1 \le (n-2) + 1 = n-1 = (n+1) -2$.

$n$ is not an integer.

$n + 1$ is not an integer.

$n$ is infinite.

If $n+1$ were finite then $n = (n+1) - 1=n$ would be finite which is a contradiction.

$n = n-1= 6$

$n+1 = (n-1)+1 = n = n-1 = 6$

and so on....